# How many ways to say "I flew..."

Tags: phrase-request

I need creative ways to say "I flew to the US." Is there anything wrong with the followings. And please add more ways. Thank you for your help.

1. I flew to the US.
2. I took a flight to the US.
3. I booked a flight to the US.
4. I traveled to the US by flying United Airline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really only two ways to express this: 1) explicitly saying you flew; or 2) by implying flying.

In your examples

> I flew to the US. *(obviously correct)*
>   I took a flight to the US.  *(obviously correct)*
>   I booked a flight to the US. *(not necessarily correct, you have a ticket but may not have flown)*
>   I traveled to the US by flying United Airlines. *(obviously correct)*

Other ways of saying it

> I went to the US by United Airlines. *(flying implied, since using an airlines)*
>   I jetted to NYC.  *(synonym for flying)*
>   We went via JFK. *(implied since JFK is an airport)*

Comment: Also "I winged my way to the US"

Comment: _"...and brother, are my arms tired!"_